# Get current time in a cell and stop it from changing

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Intuitively, one'd use `=now()` to get current time in a cell. However, every time some changes are made to the sheet, the cell's value changes to the current time. I only want to get the timestamp when the cell is filled for the first time, and it shouldn't change after that.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to insert date or time once you can apply one of these shortcuts:

> Place the cursor into the cell of interest and press one of the
> following shortcuts:
>
> Ctrl+; (semicolon) to enter the current date.
>
> Ctrl+Shift+; (semicolon) to enter the current time.
>
> Ctrl+Alt+Shift+; (semicolon) to add both,
> current date and time.

[Reference](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/date-time-google-sheets/)

Comment: What about on mobile?  There is a date/time picker which appears to default to the present, but unfortunately the time picker omits the second so it always winds up :00 which introduces inaccuracies that are hard to deal with.